What to do with grapevine cutting in autumn?
I took some cuttings off a grapevine, and attempted to grow them in water.  Although I could not really see any roots, one of the cuttings started showing signs of top growth, so I planted it in a container, which is inside my house, and slowly but surely its continued to grow.   It took a lot longer to start growing then I expected - but it looks more like a seedling then something ready to hibernate for winter!
The plant (per pic below) is about 15cm above the ground.  The leaf is about 2cm wide. Stem of "trunk" is about 3mm.
I'm in the southern hemisphere (In rural Auckland New Zealand, approx USDA hardiness zone 9), and we are in late autumn.  Most of the deciduous trees are loosing their leaves, certainly not growing new ones at this time of year.
My question is what should I be doing with this cutting now and over the next few months, and what should I expect the cutting to do ?  Should I be leaving it inside in a more controlled environment where the temperature extremes will be the most controlled, or put it in my small greenhouse (to avoid frost), or put it outside where it is going to be fully exposed to winter?
Relatedly, are there other care steps I should take (like reducing/eliminating watering if its in my house/greenhouse to avoid root rot).


@YosefBaskin  I am sure you are right - My problem is that I believe grapevines EXPECT a cold period where they die right back and loose all their leaves - but my baby is only just starting to get a very small leaf or 2 - How do I square away the annual cycle with a nascent plant that is so fragile and behaving like its in spring when its in autumn.
